# Yii2 Assets: How to use image asset inside CSS file?

Tags: css, yii2, assets, yii2-extension, yii2-module

I want to create an extension which contains an `AssetBundle`, which provides a simple static CSS file. In that static CSS file, I want to use an image file, which is also part of the extension.

How can I know the image file's URL so I can use it inside the CSS file?

If I register the image file as an asset, it will get a random URL that we **cannot predict**! So it would be impossible to do something like:

`.some-selector {
    background: url('/assets/?????/image.jpg');
}`

So, how can this be done?

---

For further  clarification, here is an example folder structure of such extension:

- `extension/Widget.php` - some widget that registers our AssetBundle
- `extension/AssetBundle.php` - asset bundle that registers the css
- `extension/assets/css/style.css` - the css
- `extension/assets/images/image.jpg` - the image we want to use inside `style.css`

Comment: What was your expected result?

Comment: @LIJINSAMUEL Having a purely static CSS file which uses an image provided by the extension.

Comment: Images in the assets folder?

Comment: .some-selector {
    background: url('assets/image.jpg');
}

Comment: @LIJINSAMUEL No, the assets are in the extension's `vendor` folder, so they are not going to be in the application's `assets` folder.

Comment: can you give me a detailed folder structure please? I cant understand what's the issue

Comment: For example: `vendor/provider/extension/assets/image.jpg` and we also want a CSS file (which needs that image), lets say `vendor/provider/extension/assets/style.css`. The issue is: how do we use `image.jpg` inside `style.css`?

Comment: Sorry am helpless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would recommend to include also a new css files into the asset definition. In this case the image and css file will be in the assets folder and you can specify relative path, not absolute. 
e.g.
/assets/a4dc56/image.jpg

/assets/a4dc56/style.css with the following content:

```
.some-selector {
    background: url('image.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. I knew there had to be an obvious solution. I ended up including the image through a relative path as such: `background: url('../images/image.jpg');`

Comment: How about using `AssetManager` just like: `$bundle = AppAsset::register($this);` then: `<img src="<?= $bundle->baseUrl.'/logo.png' ?>" />`?